# Cannot add Material Design to Angular 4 project

Tags: node.js, angular, material-design

I try to add Material Design to my project following the official tutorial  ( https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started ) but I get an error:

node_modules/@angular/cdk/typings/rxjs/rx-operators.d.ts(11,10): error TS2305: Module '"path_to_project/nod
e_modules/rxjs/Scheduler"' has no exported member 'IScheduler'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts(8,119): error TS2305: Module '"path_to_project/node_modules/@angular/animations/browser"' has no exported member 'ɵDomAnimationEngine'.

I cannot find solution in the forums.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.81",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.2.2"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

and my systemjs.config.js:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
    '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
    '@angular/cdk': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newest `material-2.0.0-beta.8` has a dependency on `@angular/cdk` which has a dependency on `rxjs` version `5.0.3` or greater.

So you have to change the `rxjs` version in your package.json:

`npm install rxjs@5.0.3 --save`

or

`"rxjs": "~5.0.3"`

Also, `@angular/animations` version 4.2.x has a know [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17400) of

> error TS2305: Module '"path_to_project/node_modules/@angular/animations/browser"' has no exported member 'ɵDomAnimationEngine'.

If you still get this error, you might need to fall back to version 4.1.x.

`npm install '@angular/animations"@4.1.3' --save`